# matplotlibでCSVから3Dサーフェスグラフを作りたい

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

pandasでcsvファイルを読み込んで3Dのサーフェスのグラフを作りたいのですが、x,y,z成分に当たる要素をcsvファイルからどう割り当てればいいかわかりません。

csvファイルは、

```
NAN 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90
1  ｘ  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
2  ｘ  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
3  ｘ  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
4  ｘ  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
5  ｘ  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

となっていて(ずれてますが6×10の行列の形です)、xのところにz成分の値が入り,
x軸を一行目の10～90
ｙ軸を一列目の1～5としたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 細かいことですが、提示されたファイル内容のままだとakitoさんが思っていらっしゃるようなCSVにはなっていないかもしれません。デリミタがカンマだったり半角スペースだったりしています。

Comment: delim_whitespace=True，header=0，data.columns.values.astype(np.float32)これらの意味が分からないんですが教えて頂けますか？

Comment: 回答に追記しました。ただ、そのあたりの情報はそのまま「delim_whitespace」や「pandas columns.values」などでググると出てくることではあります。また、公式のドキュメントにも書かれています。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サンプルプログラム

```py
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# CSVからデータを読み込む
data = pd.read_csv('./example.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

# 3Dグラフの初期化
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# データの準備
Xgrid = data.columns.values.astype(np.float32)
Ygrid = data.index.values.astype(np.float32)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(Xgrid, Ygrid)
Z = data.as_matrix()

# プロット
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

# 必要な場合はここでその他の設定をします。

# 表示
plt.show()
```

example.csv

```
    10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
1    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2    2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
3    3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
4    4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
5    5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
```

表示結果

[image: サンプルのプロット結果です]

実行した環境: Ubuntu 17.04, Python 3.6.0, pandas 0.19.2, matplotlib 2.0.0, numpy 1.13.1

---

### 解説

サンプルのプログラムを書いてみました。ポイントは「どうやってCSVを読み込むか」と「どうやって3Dサーフェスプロットするか」です。

pandas で CSV を読み込むには [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) を使います。CSV のフォーマットに合わせて適当にオプションを設定する必要があります。

3Dプロットに関しては、matplotlib の[公式チュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)が参考になります。具体的には ["Surface plots"](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) の節にあるサンプルがぴったしです。ソースコードも置いてあるので分かりやすいと思います。上に書いたソースコードはとりあえずデフォルトで表示させているだけですが、サーフェスの色など細かい設定をしたい場合はチュートリアルのソースコードを見ながらコードを追加すると良いでしょう。

<sub>細かい部分についても多少書いておきます。今回はCSVのデリミタが半角スペース複数文字のときを考えているので、そうなるように `delim_whitespace` 引数で設定します。CSVがカンマ区切りであればこれは必要ありません。詳しくは「pandas スペース区切り」などで検索してください。また、ヘッダー行が先頭のみであることが分かっているので、`header` 引数でついでに設定しています。その後「データの準備」の部分ではX軸・Y軸に相当する部分（グリッド）を作成しています。今回は dataframe の行・列ラベルをそのまま軸として使用しています。ただし場合によっては型 (dtype) を合わせておかないとエラーが出るため、最後の `astype()` で念の為 float32 にキャストしています。ここは float32 でなくても構いません。適当です。</sub>

### 参考

公式の解説です。

- [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -- pandas 0.20.3 documentation
- [mplot3d tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

また、以下のような解説サイトは「pandas csv」や「matplotlib 3d」などで検索すると簡単に出てくるので、ひとまず検索してみるのもオススメです。

- [CSVファイルの扱い](https://qiita.com/okadate/items/7b9620a5e64b4e906c42) -- pandasでよく使う文法まとめ -- Qiita
- [CSV, TSV を開く](https://qiita.com/koara-local/items/0e56bc1e58b11e4d7a32) -- pandasの使い方まとめ -- Qiita
- [matplotlibで3Dプロット](https://qiita.com/kazetof/items/c0204f197d394458022a) -- Qiita
- [Matplotlibで3Dグラフを描く](https://qiita.com/Takumi0204/items/28f35d60bef18954aabe) -- Qiita

Answer (score 0):

#### --- Update (的な) ---

(@nekketsuuu さんの回答のコードが現在では動かなくなったので, 更新)

pandas 0.23.0 以降, `as_matrix()` は非推奨になり使用できなくなりました

参考: https://pandas.pydata.org/

```
Latest version: 1.3.2
Release date: Aug 15, 2021
```

Matplotlib 3.4 で `pyplot.gca`および `Figure.gca`でのキーワード引数は非推奨になりました

参考: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.4.0.html#deprecations

---

そのような訳で, 現在では次のようなコードになります

```py
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# CSVからデータを読み込む
data = pd.read_csv('./example.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

# 3Dグラフの初期化
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d') # fig.gca(projection='3d') から変更

# データの準備
Xgrid = data.columns.values.astype(np.float32)
Ygrid = data.index.values.astype(np.float32)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(Xgrid, Ygrid)
Z = data.values # data.as_matrix() から変更

# プロット
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

# 必要な場合はここでその他の設定をします。

# 表示
plt.show()
```