# pythonでcsvから３Dグラフを描くときのエラー

Tags: python, csv

[matplotlibでCSVから3Dサーフェスグラフを作りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38367/matplotlib%E3%81%A7csv%E3%81%8B%E3%82%893d%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

このページを見て3Dグラフを作ろうとしていますが

```
could not convert string to float: ',1,2,3,4,5'
```

というエラーがでます。
いろいろ試しているんですが進めません。
解決策があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# CSVからデータを読み込む
data = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

# 3Dグラフの初期化
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# データの準備
Xgrid = data.columns.values.astype(np.float32)
Ygrid = data.index.values.astype(np.float32)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(Xgrid, Ygrid)
Z = data.as_matrix()

# プロット
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

# 表示
plt.show()
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv` で `delim_whitespace=True` としていますが、`test.csv` はカンマ区切りではないのでしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさんコメントの`delim_whitespace=True,`を削除したらそれなりの図が表示されましたよ。なお、前回の質問もそうですがサンプルデータを画像で貼り付けると、検証するのに入力の手間がかかるので手を出す人が減りそうです。データはテキストで記述した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: @kunif  ```delim_whitespace=True,```を消したら```could not convert string to float: 'Unnamed: 0'```というエラーが出てしまいます、、、。なるほどテキストの方がいいんですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ああ、済みません。データを色々いじっていたので間違えました。一番最初のデータを空ではなく0にするか、各行の最初の列を削除してみてください。あるいは、結局プログラムは変更せず参照元記事のようにカンマ区切りでは無く空白やタブで区切ったデータにするとか。

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございますできました質問の仕方も学んでいきます、、、。また機会がありましたら宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因は、参照元回答の以下の部分を見落としたか良く理解していなかったためでしょう。
太字にした部分に気を付けて、データファイルをカンマ区切りではなく空白区切りにするか、プログラムを変える必要があったわけです。

> サンプルのプログラムを書いてみました。ポイントは「どうやってCSVを読み込むか」と「どうやって3Dサーフェスプロットするか」です。
>
> pandas で CSV を読み込むには[read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)を使います。CSV のフォーマットに合わせて適当にオプションを設定する必要があります。
>
> 細かい部分についても多少書いておきます。**今回はCSVのデリミタが半角スペース複数文字のときを考えているので、そうなるように`delim_whitespace`引数で設定します。CSVがカンマ区切りであればこれは必要ありません。詳しくは「pandas スペース区切り」などで検索してください。**

まあ、私も実は読んでいなかったので、ちょっとトンチンカンなコメントをしてしまいました。

参照元回答の参考リンクなども良く読んでおきましょう。